# OpenCL clEnqueueReadBuffer segfaults randomly

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, opencl

I'm having a hard time determining why a segmentation fault occurs randomly at the following line in my code:

```
rc = clEnqueueReadBuffer(ompctx->clctx->queue,
                ompctx->result, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), &pos,
                1, &ompctx->clctx->ev1, NULL);
```

ompctx->result is a memory object used as an array of integers and pos is a host object declared as:

```
int pos
```

I tried with pos declared on the stack and in the global space and the result doesn't change.
I tried with waiting for the last kernel to finish (as above, although I shouldn't because I have an in-order command queue) and without waiting, the result is still the same.

I'm using AMD APP v2.8 and I tried on an i7 with 8 CPUs and on a AMD FirePro v8800. Both exhibit the same problem.

Am I missing something obvious? What else should I check for?

Comment: Maybe you are dereferencing a `null` pointer? Without seeing more code it will be hard to tell.

Comment: I print the pointers and they all look okay before the call to ReadBuffer. The queue is used right before this call and it always succeeds, the result is used with success as well, pos is a global variable and the events don't make any difference if they're there or not. So I don't think it's a null pointer dereference.

Comment: Have you tried using the Intel OpenCL platform? Does it give you the same error?

Comment: Did you check the return value of all OpenCL calls up to that point?

Comment: ananthonline: No, but I thought about it. Thing is I need the AMD one, but it can't hurt to clear up that it's not the implementation's fault.
Eric Bainville: Yes, each and every one. Always.

Comment: Interesting, calling just clFinish() on the queue before the offending read crashes the application inside the OpenCL implementation.

Comment: Your kernels may be writing out of the buffers/images.  It frequently leads to this kind of random issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have the blocking argument set to CL_TRUE, clEnqueueReadBuffer will not return until the transfer is completed, which means that all of the previous commands enqueued before the transfer will also have to be completed. It is likely that one of your previous OpenCL calls enqueued a command that writes out of bounds or something (because it happens randomly) and the command is not executed until clEnqueueReadBuffer is called. Try calling clFinish on your command queue after each OpenCL call you make to force each command to complete right after it's enqueued, and insert a couple printf statements so you can figure out which one is really failing.

Comment: I ended up doing that and followed the crash to the cl blas library from amd. Forgot about adding the solution here, thanks for that :-)